# How do I verify a message containing Unicode character points using Python's Cryptography library

Tags: javascript, python, unicode, cryptography, base64

I've been using the python cryptography library for a while now and have a question about verifying signatures of payloads containing unicode...

Is this something that the library officially supports? I have been unable to get an exception (only silent failure) when passing in bytes that are not plain ascii to the 'message' (2nd) argument of the RSA verify method

https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#verification

My application currently generates a signature on a device using JS and I would like to verify the signature and message using python, however there are slight discrepancies between the base64 serialization processes of each language and this may be a sign that I'm barking up the wrong tree...

Here's what my verification code looks like in python:

```
try:
  public_key.verify(
     base64.b64decode(signature),
     message.encode('utf8', 'strict'),
     padding.PSS(
       mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
       alt_length=20
     ),
     hashes.SHA256()
  )
except Exception as e:
  print("This is run, but e is empty when the message has non-ascii characters")
```

and it successfully verifies messages as long as they only contain ASCII characters. Any non-ascii characters within the message makes the call to verify fail while raising an empty exception.

Any help understanding this signature verification for unicode characters would be greatly appreciated! Thanks...

Comment: The printed message in the code seems to contradict what you write in the text: you write that there is no exception, but the print message suggests that an exception *is* raised, but it is "empty" (whatever that means). Can you be more clear about what happens really?

Comment: The exception _is_ raised, but it is empty. Clarified in the post ty.

Comment: I don't understand what an empty exception is. Can you show the full traceback? (You'll have to add `raise` after the `print` statement.)

Comment: Part of the issue is that the exception doesn't seem to provide any further information! I know one's bubbling up from somewhere bceause the code in the block is run, however whatever I do to try and print it (the exception, e), e.__dict__, it comes up as an empty string! So this is what I meant by an empty exception...

Comment: Please include the traceback in your post. It will at least tell us the type of the exception and the line where it was raised.